# In graph theory, what is the difference between a component of a graph and a block of a graph?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm using the book *Balakrishnan, R., & Ranganathan, K. (2012). A textbook of graph theory, Springer*. In graph theory, what is the difference between a component of a graph and a block of a graph?

Comment: Please rephrase your question. What does *"Balakrishnan, R., & Ranganathan, K. (2012). A textbook of graph theory. Springer this book."* mean?

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, a block of a (simple, undirected) graph is a maximally 2-vertex-connected subgraph. A graph is 2-vertex-connected, if it has at least 2 vertices and you can delete any vertex of it and it still is connected.

Reading component without any further explanation, I will think of a connected component, which means a maximally connected subgraph.

For example the graph of the shape $\triangleright\!\triangleleft$ is connected (hence has only one component), but has *two* blocks. The whole graph is not 2-vertex-connected, because deleting the center vertex makes the resulting graph disconnected. Any of the two triangles $\triangleright$ and $\triangleleft$ are 2-vertex-connected though. And these are the maximal 2-vertex-connected subgraphs, since any larger subgraph basically looks like $\triangleright\!-$ or is the whole graph, which are both not 2-vertex-connected.

Comment: I'm just confirming that you are recalling correctly: the reference given by the OP defines a block as a maximally 2-vertex-connected subgraph (though not in that exact language).